# How to create alert if the letter x is pressed on the keyboard

Tags: jquery

I would like to trigger an alert if the letter x is selected. I looked up the keycode and it is 88. This works when using the enter key and keycode.

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '88'){
        alert('You pressed the letter x');   
    }
});
```

Comment: Note: `keypress` returns code 120 but `keyup` returns code 88. Not sure why, but be aware of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `keyup` and also put the ternary operator in brackets:

```
$(document).keyup(function(event){
    var keycode = ((event.keyCode) ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '88'){
        alert('You pressed the letter x');   
    }
});
```